# Find self and parent tag in XML document

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have a list of terms (string) which may or may not be present in a given XML document. I need to look for this string in the attribute values and if it is found, return its own tag and its parent's tag. How can I do this in Java?

EDIT:
I came across multiple ways using DOM Parser or SAX Parser or write one myself. I want to know the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: what have you tried? did you search for the millions question addressing how to parse an xml document? and what does the xml look like? what is the term that you are looking for? this question is very poor in quality and you should edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself.
I used this

```
SAXParserFactory spfac = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spfac.newSAXParser();
EMSAXParser handler = new EMSAXParser(this.terms);
```

Then I implemented the following methods while using a stack to push in for every start and pop out for every end tag. And when text is founf, a search is done and then if the term is found in the text then the upper two elements of the stack are peeked.

```
startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes);
characters(char[] buffer, int start, int length);
endElemnet(String uri, String localName, String qName);
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath; for example, `//*[@* = 'something']` will match all e.g. `<a b="something"/>`, `<a b="c" d="something"><e f="g"/></a>` etc.

As for using XPath in Java, check the following page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

[The Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://jaxp.java.net/)

> The Java API for XML Processing (JAXP) enables applications to parse,
>   transform, validate and query XML documents using an API that is
>   independent of a particular XML processor implementation. JAXP
>   provides a pluggability layer to enable vendors to provide their own
>   implementations without introducing dependencies in application code.

[The Java XPath API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html)

> XPath expressions are much easier to write than detailed Document
>   Object Model (DOM) navigation code. When you need to extract
>   information from an XML document, the quickest and simplest way is to
>   embed an XPath expression inside your Java program. Java 5 introduces
>   the javax.xml.xpath package, an XML object-model independent library
>   for querying documents with XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You could run an XPath expression on the Xml document:

```
InputSource source= new InputSource(new FileInputStream(doc)));
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate("//@*[. = \'" + myString + "\']", source, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

You can then use the resulting NodeList to get the containing node objects and their parent nodes.